# How can I insert an image from a file input into a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to allow a user to click a file upload button, select a file, and have that file immediately display wherever they are typing in a contenteditable div. I have a solution that works inconsistently, and seems to depend on which element is focused before the file upload is clicked.

This is similar to this question, except that I cannot get the proposed solution to work reliably:

[insert image inside a contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55137151/insert-image-inside-a-contenteditable-div)

Here is an example that works sometimes, but every time I run it it is hard to predict whether or not the image will show. I'm trying to make this work reliably.

https://jsfiddle.net/0tdgc49k/1/

Note that I am clicking on the label, not the input element, which should trigger the same event. Uploads using the input element seem more reliable, although I would ideally like to get the label element working because it is easier to style.

```js
function pasteImage() {
 document.getElementById("output").focus();
 var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
   document.getElementById("output").focus();
   document.execCommand('insertImage', false, e.target.result);
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("input").files[0]);
}

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener('input', pasteImage);
document.getElementById("output").focus();
```

```css
input {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<label for="input">Upload Photo</label>
<input id="input" type="file" accept="image/*">
<div id="output" tabindex="0" contenteditable="true">Editable Content</div>
```

I expect that every time I click "Upload Image" and select an image from my harddrive, it will become visible in the contenteditable div. Sometimes it does, but if I repeatedly run the fiddle and attempt the upload again, it fails about half the time. This result is consistent across both the fiddle and the local html page on which I developed it, so it is not just an artifact of the fiddle.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, what Browser are you using?

Comment: _This result is consistent across both the fiddle and the local html page on which I developed it_ What is the problem then?

Comment: @weegee as he stated, it doesn`t always work... not in the fiddle, nor on the local page. - therefor ist consistent - but not working ;) seems like a browser issue to me, because it DOES WORK 100% of the time in my browser.

Comment: @DigitalJedi  am using Firefox 66 on Ubuntu 16.04. However, on further investigation, I cannot reproduce it either on Chrome or Firefox for Android. Perhaps it is a browser bug? Should I close the question?

Comment: @Apocalypse Mystic - If you are OK with it, close the question... I definitly think its a browser thing...

Comment: @DigitalJedi do you want to submit that as an answer? I think that's what's going on here. Might as well leave it up I suppose in case someone else runs into it.

Comment: I submitted an answer, as this really seems to be a browser issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Firefox:**

I can upload as many fotos as I want, in any order I want, as many times in a row, and it is giving me no problems **whatsoever**

2. **Chrome:**

When uploading a sequence like: *pic1 -  pic1 - pic1 - pic1*,  only the first image is uploaded.

When uploading a sequence like: *pic1 - pic2 - pic1 - pic2*,  all the pictures are uploaded.

When uploading a sequence like: *pic1 - pic1 - pic2 -pic2*, the first instance of *pic1* is uploaded, and the first instance of *pic2* is uploaded

3. **IE**

The same thing that happens in Chrome also goes for Internet Explorer...

I Dont think it`s a contenteditable issue, as it is very widly supported:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable

This leads me to the conclusion that this is a **browser issue**.